# Parsing txt file with multiple delimiters

Tags: python, parsing

I have a data.txt file that contains the interactions between objects w.r.t the distance between them. As a small example, let's say I have objects a,b,c,A,B,C; and I measured their interactions for just one distance value. Then the format of the output looks like this:

```
header
    Distance aA bA cA
             aB bB cB
             aC bC cC
```

Below is a small real example

```
% rows 3 cols 10
    0.001000     0.270443    -0.276056     0.277961
                 0.241303     0.227167     0.227000
                -0.238565     0.257939     0.275644
    0.002000     0.126853     0.121890     0.115652
                 0.137218     0.136350     0.132567
                 0.116713     0.113115     0.111461
    0.003000     0.201059     0.184873    -0.170027
                 0.132424    -0.122704    -0.112826
                 0.089461     0.086023     0.084290
```

I want to parse this data file and reshape it to a matrix that actually has the size given in the header (3x10 in this example) so that I can plot the specific interactions w.r.t. distance.

The first problem is of course the distance column because of the space between each value. So as a first try, I removed the distance column (since I already know this data), and tried to just parse the interaction terms with below code:

```
     import numpy as np

     with open('data.txt', 'r') as the_file:
         all_data = [line.strip() for line in the_file.readlines()]
         header = all_data[0].split()
         row=int(header[2])
         cols=int(header[4])

     lines=np.loadtxt("data.txt", delimiter="     ", skiprows=1)
         a=np.reshape(lines, (row,cols));
```

, but the negative values mess up the delimiter. So my question is, how can I parse this file (keeping the distance column if possible)?

I know this is a very specific question, but I'll appreciate even a small nudge in the right direction. I already tried `np.split` and `pandas` libraries but couldn't get the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude "solution" (which assumes the datafile is perfectly formatted):

```py
with open('matrix.dat', 'r') as data_file:
    rows, cols = [int(c) for c in data_file.readline().split() if c.isnumeric()]
    array = np.fromstring(data_file.read(), sep=' ').reshape(rows, cols)
```

And here's a probably unnecessary alternative which avoids reading the entire file as a single string:

```py
import itertools
chainstar = itertools.chain.from_iterable
with open('matrix.dat', 'r') as data_file:
    rows, cols = [int(c)
                  for c in data_file.readline().split()
                  if c.isnumeric()]
    array = np.fromiter(chainstar(map(lambda s:s.split(), data_file)),
                        dtype=np.float,
                        count=rows*cols).reshape(rows, cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach may be to use a regular expression to parse the values in the file:

```
import re

f = open('data.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
expr = r'\-?\d+.\d*'
expr_compiled = re.compile(expr)

data_values = [expr_compiled.findall(l) for l in lines]
```

In the example, `data_values` would be a conventional list of lists containing something like this:

```
[['0.001000', '0.270443', '-0.276056', '0.277961'],
 ['0.241303', '0.227167', '0.227000'],
 ['-0.238565', '0.257939', '0.275644'],
 ['0.002000', '0.126853', '0.121890', '0.115652'],
 ['0.137218', '0.136350', '0.132567'],
 ['0.116713', '0.113115', '0.111461'],
 ['0.003000', '0.201059', '0.184873', '-0.170027'],
 ['0.132424', '-0.122704', '-0.112826'],
 ['0.089461', '0.086023', '0.084290']]
```

Of course, this would require you to transform every value to a valid number in order to perform maths with them and to extract the first value from some of those lists, given that those values represent something different.

Finally, you can use numpy arrays and reshape them like you want.

Answer (score -1):

If you're storing the values as floats, then simply reduce the delimiter by one space.  The leading space on positive values won't hurt the value conversion.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. That solves my problem unless I keep the distance column.